# MySQL fails to start

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, mysql

I was testing a Magento shop and suddenly mysql stopped working and fails to restart. Any ideas how to get it working again? I have magento running on Apache and Varnish if that's useful information.

```
/var/log/mysql.err shows this kind of error:

130826 14:20:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130826 14:20:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect file format 'plugin'
130826 14:20:04 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130826 14:20:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130826 14:20:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130826 14:20:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130826 14:20:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130826 14:20:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130826 14:20:04 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130826 14:20:04  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
130826 14:20:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130826 14:20:05 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 6690661
130826 14:20:05 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
130826 14:20:05 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
130826 14:20:05 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
130826 14:20:05 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format '$
130826 14:20:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

SOLUTION:

I found a solution to this problem of mine. The key was the fatal error at the bottom of that error listing.

Reconstruct the main tables host, user and db. First:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
tar czf /root/mysql.tgz mysql
cd mysql
rm -rf *
mysql_install_db
```

At this point I had to start MySQL.

Grant permission for 'debian-sys-maint' user. Password for that user will be present in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

```
GRANT SHUTDOWN ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' identified by '7868hugbYVHVTYHBMH';
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' identified by '7868hugbYVHVTYHBMH';
```

Then I had to add a new user to database with new password and configure those again to Magento. After that I just cleared the cache and session folders and Magento started working again.

Comment: I think this is off topic. I think you might get help here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about databases not magento. http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Can%27t+open+and+lock+privilege+tables%3A+Incorrect+file+format+%27%24

Comment: Magento server issues will get quicker answers if you determine the underlying subsystem and ask questions in the proper venue. In this case, something is severely wrong with MySQL which is preventing Magento from running and expertise in running MySQL is needed to fix it.

Comment: Great. Please post it as an answer and mark it as solution.